# Increment through base-n numbers

Tags: python, iteration, radix

I am trying to increment through all of the possible base-n numbers, where numbers are represented by a list of chars.

For example,

For base-5 numbers (where `n = 5`) limited to 4 places, and the base 5 numbers are represented by the list:

```
digits=['a','b','c','d','e']
```

incrementation would look like

```
a, b, c, d, e, aa, ab, ac, ad, ae, ba, bb, bc, ... , eeee
```

What is the most pragmatic approach in python to do this where `n=5` or `n=105`

Comment: So, do you have 2 inputs: the array `digits=['a','b','c','d','e']` (`n` can be obtained by getting the size of that array) and `maximumNumberOfDigits=4`?

Comment: Essentially only one input `maximumNumberOfDigits` since the n comes from `len(digits)` as you had mentioned

Answer (score 5):

You can get the result with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), like this

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> base = 3
>>> ["".join(item) for i in range(1, base) for item in product('abcde', repeat=i)])
['a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'e',
 'aa',
 'ab',
 'ac',
 'ad',
 'ae',
 'ba',
 'bb',
 'bc',
 'bd',
 'be',
 'ca',
 'cb',
 'cc',
 'cd',
 'ce',
 'da',
 'db',
 'dc',
 'dd',
 'de',
 'ea',
 'eb',
 'ec',
 'ed',
 'ee']
```

> What is the most pragmatic approach in python to do this where n=5 or n=105

I would say, don't create the list at all. You might exhaust the computer's memory. Better use the iterator and use the value as and when you need it. That is exactly why `product` returns an iterator.